# What's the difference between the different Rig Types ? (Rigify add-on)

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I've made a metarig (a ready-to-use skeleton) for a character mesh and I've added some extra bones for the feet (my character has long floppy flippers). For each new bone, I need to assign a "Rig type". To do so, in "Pose Mode", I select my new bone and I go to the "Bone Panel" and I scroll down to "Rigify Type" and "Rig type". Here there is a all variety of usable types of rigs...

[image]

My question is: With Rigify, what's the difference between the different types of rigs and in which situations should we choose one specific type of rig instead of another ?

Answer (score 1):

> Rig Types are the Properties Collection used by Rigify to identify
>   what kind of rig the user is building.

Choice should depend on what controls you want to get for your bones.

Rig types description is in link below.

https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify/#Rigify_Rig_Types